# How can I make a 'const tm*' from a 'const tm&'?

Tags: c++

```
namespace abc{
    class MyClass{
    protected:
       tm structTime;
    public:
       const tm& getTM(){
            return structTime;
        }
       void foo(){ std::string tmp = asctime ( this->getTM() ); }
    };
```

The above code gives me this error:

```
 error: cannot convert 'const tm' to 'const tm*' for argument '1' to 'char* asctime(const tm*)'
```

I then changed the code to this:

```
std::string tmp = asctime ( static_cast<const tm*>(getTM()) );
```

but that gives me an error that says:

```
invalid static_cast from type 'const tm' to type 'const tm*'
```

**How can I make a 'const tm*' from a 'const tm&'?**

Answer (score 4):

> *`static_cast<const tm*>(getTM())`*

You **certainly don't want** a `static_cast<>` (nor a `reinterpret_cast<>`) to do this!

See the reference for [`std::asctime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/asctime), it wants a pointer actually:

```
char* asctime( const std::tm* time_ptr );
                         // ^
```

> *"How can I make a 'const tm*' from a 'const tm&'?"*

Your function returns a `const &`, that's not a pointer. Change your code to pass the address of the result:

```
asctime ( &getTM() );
       // ^ <<<< Take the address of the result, to make it a const pointer
```

<sub>See a complete ***[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/pmLiYK)***.</sub>

---

You may also be interested in reading this Q&A:

[**What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Comment: @Jamiil _"Yes, you are right!"_ Did you consider accepting the answer then? It might help future researchers to judge this Q&A pair being helpful.

Comment: @Jamiil This will also support to avoid silly feature requests [like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277918/should-users-with-high-rep-be-able-to-accept-answers-to-questions-with-no-accept) appearing on MSO.